# How are segment types distinguished from one another?

Tags: x86, x86-64, hardware, intel, gdt

How are different types of segment identified as different? Wikipedia states:

> Segments can be defined to be either code, data, or system segments

It also states:

> Descriptors with bit 12 clear are "system descriptors" and are used
>   for specialized purposes.

So, I gather that this "system bit" is used to identify a system segment, but what about code and data segments? Additionally, since these identifiers are stored separately instead of as a single 2-bit value, can you get combination-types, like system code and system data segments?

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table says the Ex bit makes a descriptor a code-segment descriptor instead of data.  https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial#What_should_i_put_in_my_GDT.3F also has more details on what kinds of GDT entries there can be.  If you want the full details, see Intel's manuals (vol.3 especially).  Links in the x86 tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Type* field of a segment descriptor is not one bit but four.

[image: Format of a segment descriptor with 1 bit for the system/non-system type and 4 bit of sub type]

The *S* field defines if the descriptor is a system descriptor (bit is clear) or not.
The interpretation of the *Type* field depends on the value of *S*.

**Non system descriptors**

[image: Non system descriptors]

**System descriptors**

[image: System descriptors]

---

To better understand how protected/long mode segmentation works I advice you dropping Wikipedia in favour of the Intel manuals.